# Too slow socket response (21 seconds) using TCP protocol

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, network-programming

I am trying to create socket and connect to a device. The problem occurs when the device is not in the network and I try to connect. I get false as response (which is ok and on which base I update status of my device), but the problem is that I get the response in 21 seconds. I am using this function to connect:

```
public bool Connect(IPEndPoint ipEndPoint, IPAddress ipAddress, Guid id, bool isAlive)
{
    try
    {
          clSocket = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
          clSocket.NoDelay = false;
          clSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
          clSocket.SendTimeout = 1000;
          clSocket.Connect(ipEndPoint);
          return true;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          return false;
     }
}
```

As much as I read about "21 seconds timeout" I found out that I have to change the register:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters

Value Name:  TcpMaxDataRetransmissions

Data Type:   REG_DWORD - Number

Valid Range: 0 - 0xFFFFFFFF

Default:     3**

I am reffering to this articles:
http://getin2me.blogspot.com/2010/08/are-you-also-facing-windows-sockets-21.html 
and this post:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fd586377-34b3-4cb8-a3af-0a24c608e399/connectex-winsock-question?forum=vcgeneral

Why in Windows 8 I can not find this register? Is there any other solution so I can get quick (by quick I mean normal <1ms to <20ms i.e.) response true(connected) or false(not connected)?

Comment: These registry keys are not present by default.  They are only meant to *extend* the timeouts.

Comment: So I should add them or...?

Answer (score 1):

> by quick I mean normal <1ms to <20ms i.e.)

If the device is not there you can not get a response about the failed connection that fast. A TCP connections gets established by the [3-way-handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment). In this handshake the client first sends a SYN packet to the server and waits for the SYN+ACK back.

- If the server is there but the port is closed it will send a RST back (instead of SYN+ACK) and the client knows that that the server is unreachable. This can be done in RTT time, which is a few ms in a local network but can be easily more than 20ms if you are on the internet.
- If the server is not there it can not send a response back. In this case the client will retry to send the SYN multiple times because the packet might simply be lost. How long it will wait for the response depends on the OS and tuning, but often the first retry is done after 1 second, the second after 3 seconds... until after some time the client simply gives up and assumes the server is not there. This means in this case it will take multiple seconds and there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I completely agree with everything you wrote, but if you read the articles that i posted you will see that it is possible to set TcpMaxDataRetransmissions and tune the OS to give up after the 1'st call. You know maybe how i can tune that in Win8?

Comment: No I don't. But even if you do this it would be hard to get the response within 20ms, because probably the OS will wait longer before giving up. And trying only once will get you a failed connection in lots of cases where the server is up because loosing packets from time to time is actually a normal behavior.

Comment: OK, I would say reasonable time not 20ms, but to achieve that i need to change time of waiting for response, instead of 3s, 6s, 12s (all together 21 sec) to lower values.

Comment: I don't know how you can tune this in windows, but you could use non-blocking sockets and thus have full control how long you will wait. As an example see http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/168704/How-to-set-a-socket-connection-timeout. And this has the advantage that it applies only to a single socket and not to all sockets on the system as a global tuning in the registry would do.

Answer (score 0):

You could try pinging the address first and see if you get a response, if you dont, dont attempt to try to connect to it

```
Ping pinger = new Ping();
try
{
    PingReply reply = pinger.Send(ip);
    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: It is not the problem if I get true or false on Connect function, the problem is the timeout. Ping is something different, if you can ping it does not mean that you can send packets to device. So this does not solve my problem.

Comment: Ping (ICMP) is frequently blocked by firewalls while a TCP connection to a specific port would not be.